# Why am I getting HTTP Status 404 - Not Found?

Tags: rhel, tomcat

I'm very new to Artifactory. I just got Artifactory Tomcat started on my webserver using RHEL 7. When I try to access my page: http://myPage:8081/artifactory/webapp/#/home, I get:

```
    HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

    Type Status Report

    Message /artifactory/webapp/

    Description The origin server did not find a current representation for 
    the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

    Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
```

I've looked around and one solution was to change the http to httpd which I've tried with no luck. Where do I go from here? What logs should I look at? I've looked at catalina.out logs, all I'm seeing are warnings. Thanks in advance for help! Please let me know if their is any other information for me to provide.

**EDIT:** When I received this warning:

```
    WARNING: Failed to create work directory 
    [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/artifactory] for 
    context [/artifactory].
```

I changed my permissions for 
        artifactory.system.properties which is now fine. None of my log files 
        are showing any warning or errors except for catalina.

catalina log:

```
    16-Sep-2019 10:52:32.221 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] 
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more                 
    listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate 
    container log file
    16-Sep-2019 10:52:32.222 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] 
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context 
    [/artifactory] startup failed due to previous errors
    16-Sep-2019 10:52:32.260 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] 
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The 
    web application [artifactory] registered the JDBC driver 
    [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web 
    application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has 
    been forcibly unregistered.
    16-Sep-2019 10:52:32.265 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] 
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads 
    The web application [artifactory] appears to have started a thread named 
    [Thread-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a 
    memory leak.
```

From what I have seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617732/how-to-check-container-log-of-tomcat about "Full details will be found in the appropriate container log." It says to check a localhost.log file. When I check my localhost.log file it show's an error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Properties file artifactory.properties doesn't exist

Comment: perhaps you need to read the warning messages

Comment: The warning I'm getting is: WARNING: Failed to create work directory [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/artifactory] for context [/artifactory]. I'm guessing this is a permissions issue?

Comment: I changed permissions where the warnings indicated. Still showing HTTP Status 404 - Not Found. Are there any other logs to look at?

Comment: Include this information in the question, as it is essential.

Comment: The warning is a real problem, but probably not this caused the 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning messages actually have nothing to do with the HTTP Status 404 error.

To resolve this,

1. I restored the access.xml file located here: `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/` by taking the access backup file and copying it as access.xml.
2. It then complained about a missing join.key file. To fix that you need to match the jfrog.join.key.paths variable to `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME` path variable a the bottom of `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/default`.

After doing these steps, thee artifactory home page now displays.