# Why is Artifactory returning 404?

Tags: rhel, amazon-linux

I have installed Artifactory on Amazon Linux 2, but when I go to

http://`domain`:8081/artifactory/

it just returns

> **HTTP Status 404 – Not Found**

It is a new installation and I have not changed any configuration. I have only installed it using the provided RPM and connected it to a PostgreSQL RDS instance.

/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log/console.log contains the following

```
2023-02-03T17:25:33.664Z [jfint] [INFO ] [54433008cb1b7bc1] [security_keys.go:163          ] [main                ] - Master key is missing. Pending for 115 seconds with 2m0s timeout [startup]
2023-02-03T17:25:34.094Z [jfcon] [INFO ] [25766041ca3801f3] [security_keys.go:163          ] [main                ] - Master key is missing. Pending for 115 seconds with 2m0s timeout [startup]
2023-02-03T17:25:36.687Z [jfrou] [FATAL] [695c435436df16dd] [bootstrap.go:99               ] [main                ] [] - Failed resolving master key: failed resolving 'shared.security.masterKey' key; file does not exist: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/security/master.key
2023-02-03T17:25:37.048Z [jfmd ] [ERROR] [                ] [keys.go:23                    ] [main                ] - Failed resolving master key: failed resolving 'shared.security.masterKey' key; file does not exist: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/security/master.key
2023-02-03T17:26:38.891Z [jffe ] [INFO ] [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - pinging artifactory attempt number 180 failed with code : ECONNREFUSED
2023-02-03T17:26:39.893Z [jffe ] [ERROR] [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - Error starting application - Error: Failed pinging artifactory for 180connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8046
2023-02-03T17:26:39.894Z [jffe ] [INFO ] [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - exit detected
```

Running `systemctl artifactory status` returns the following.

```
● artifactory.service - Artifactory service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/artifactory.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-02-03 17:23:39 UTC; 54min ago
  Process: 7325 ExecStop=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/artifactoryManage.sh stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7836 ExecStart=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/artifactoryManage.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11148 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/artifactory.service
           ‣ 11148 /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/third-party/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassL...
```

During a run of `systemctl restart artifactory`, the 404 does disappear and is replaced by `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`, which suggests that it is trying to do something while the service is running.

I have seen "[Why am I getting HTTP Status 404 - Not Found?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/541196/559285)" which seems similar, but I cannot see the files that it mentions. What am I doing wrong?